# ReactJS: What does "this.setState(defaultDogs);" mean in this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm evaluating a React application (see the code below). I know what the meaning of `setState` props etc. is, and the overall working of it but I don't get the meaning of the following: `this.setState(defaultDogs);`

I wondered if that is a shorthand for the standard state update. I'm unsure if it updates the Dogs state or adds a new one instead.

Here's the code where that statement is, followed by `// <<<<<<<<<<:`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dogs from './components/Dogs';
import DogItem from './components/DogItem';
import AddDog from './components/AddDog';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dogs: []
    };
  }

  getDogs() {
    var defaultDogs = {dogs: [
      {
        name: 'Princess',
        breed: 'Corgi',
        image: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/51/ae/30/51ae30b78696b33a64661fa3ac205b3b.jpg'
      },
      {
        name: 'Riley',
        breed: 'Husky',
        image: 'http://portland.ohsohandy.com/images/uploads/93796/m/nice-and-sweet-siberian-husky-puppies-for-free-adoption.jpg'
      },
    ]};
    this.setState(defaultDogs); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getDogs();
  }

  handleAddDog(dog) {
    let dogs = this.state.dogs;
    dogs.push(dog);
    this.setState({dogs:dogs});
  }

  handleDeleteDog(name) {
    let dogs = this.state.dogs;
    let index = dogs.findIndex(x => x.name === name);
    dogs.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({dogs:dogs});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Dogs dogs={this.state.dogs} onDelete={this.handleDeleteDog.bind(this)} />
        <AddDog addDog={this.handleAddDog.bind(this)} />
        <hr />
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried running that code and logging out what `this.state` contains?

Comment: It is just putting the value of `defaultDogs` in `setState` function which is an object. So this is same as `this.setState({dogs: [...]})`

Comment: @Joe, Sagar Jajoriya  when i add console.log(this.state); in the componentWillMount() or in the getDogs() it returns: Object { dogs: [] }

Comment: @user374324 in `getDogs`, replace `this.setState(defaultDogs);` with `this.setState(defaultDogs), () => console.log(this.state));`.  `setState` will then call console.log when it completes its state update. State updates occur asynchrounously, so providing such a callback is the only way to immediately observe the result.  You can also log state from `render()` to see the progression.

Comment: @Dylan I have added this.setState(defaultDogs,() => console.log(this.state.dogs)); and yes my assumption has been verified. That is it sets the new value of the Dogs state; Since it is the only state of the App. I wonder why that state change is visible in the render but not soon after this.setState(defaultDogs). componentWillMount() is executed first then the getDogs() so Dogs is set to its value that is visible just with the way you mentioned not with console.log(this.state.dogs). I miss the asynchronous thing. Thank you.

Comment: Ah ok, in the official documentation there is the answer I was looking for: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

`setState` performs a shallow merge of the state and the passed parameter (i.e. it will replace the value of `dogs` in state with the value of `dogs` in the parameter). After that line, the state is:

```
{
  dogs: [
    {
      name: 'Princess',
      breed: 'Corgi',
      image: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/51/ae/30/51ae30b78696b33a64661fa3ac205b3b.jpg'
    },
    {
      name: 'Riley',
      breed: 'Husky',
      image: 'http://portland.ohsohandy.com/images/uploads/93796/m/nice-and-sweet-siberian-husky-puppies-for-free-adoption.jpg'
    }
  ]
}
```

Adding is done as in `handleAddDog`, by taking current state, and replacing it with a new state that has an extra dog (ideally without modifying the previous state, which is not reflected in the code above).

EDIT: The previous statement was wrong.

Since `setState` is asynchronous, you will not be able to observe the change in state directly in the function where it is called. You may see it from within a callback provided as a second parameter to `setState`, as the callback will be called when the state update is complete.

Comment: when i add console.log(this.state); in the componentWillMount() or in the getDogs() it returns: Object { dogs: [] } the only state found with an empty array.

Comment: Sorry, yours is not the answer.

Comment: May you formulate a code example of what you mean pls?

Answer (score 0):

It's replacing value of'dogs' property in state.

Comment: when i add console.log(this.state); in the componentWillMount() or in the getDogs() it returns: Object { dogs: [] } the only state found with an empty array.

Comment: Sorry, yours is not the answer.

Comment: It takes time to update state. You can't get mutated 'state' just after 'setState' call. use callBack. setState({blah: 'blah'}, function() {console(this.state);}). And 'componentWillMount' gets called before mounting and when it's mounted it will not get called until unMounted.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a shorthand of the standard state update because you give the function an object. that's the same as if you were writing:
this.setState({dogs:[...]})

a shortened spelling would be
this.setState({dogs:dogs});
this.setState({dogs})

Comment: when i add console.log(this.state); in the componentWillMount() or in the getDogs() it returns: Object { dogs: [] } the only state found with an empty array.

Comment: Sorry, yours is not the answer.

Answer (score -2):

It sets the variable `dogs` in state with `defaultDogs.dogs` variable contents.

Comment: That state has not been defined in the constructor along with the Dogs one as you may see; So I don't think yours is the answer.

Comment: You're thinking of `.setState( {defaultDogs} )`. This one is just the variable without the curly brackets.